# Dbeaver: How to expand column names in table's 'data' tab

Tags: macos, dbeaver

For a table with many columns, the columns are significantly minimized to the point where I can't even see the names or previews of the data in the rows.

How can I expand all the columns so I can at least see the column names (allowing me to see data in the rows)?

As you can see below, the only columns I can see are *user_id* and *about*.
[image]

Manually expanding each one is not something I'd like to do.

I don't have this issue on Windows, just the Mac version.

Edit: Even when I expand the tabs manually, I can't see the data inside the rows. I basically can't even use dbeaver for manual sanity checks. I'm currently having to hit my database with curl commands to check if data is being stored correctly :(

Comment: You'll get more success at its repository: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues